# TypeError: EnvironHeaders([•••]) is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, python-2.x, werkzeug

I want to turn incoming HTTP requests' headers into dictionaries and clone then via the "JSON trick." `request.headers` is an object that acts like a dictionary, but actually isn't a dictionary.

```
json.loads(json.dumps(request.headers))
```

The above-mentioned line of code results in this error:

> TypeError: EnvironHeaders([•••]) is not JSON serializable

How do I convert a `werkzeug.datastructures.EnvironHeaders` object to a dictionary?

---

**Attempt #1:**

```
json.loads(json.dumps({k: v for k, v in request.headers.iteritems()}))
```

**Attempt #2:**

```
json.loads(json.dumps({k: request.headers[k] for k in request.headers.keys()}))
```

Both of them throw this exception:

> ValueError: too many values to unpack

Answer (score 4):

Here is a minimal example that works for sure

```
headers = werkzeug.datastructures.Headers()
headers.add('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
headers.add('X-Foo', 'bar')
json.dumps({k:v for k, v in headers.iteritems()})
```

Even if you are using `EnvironHeaders`,

```
env = {
    'HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE':        'text/html',
    'CONTENT_TYPE':             'text/html',
    'HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH':      '0',
    'CONTENT_LENGTH':           '0',
    'HTTP_ACCEPT':              '*',
    'wsgi.version':             (1, 0)
}
headers = werkzeug.datastructures.EnvironHeaders(env)
json.dumps({k:v for k, v in headers.iteritems()})
```

(Examples copied from [test cases in werkzeug](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/master/tests/test_datastructures.py).)

Have you inspected `request.headers.items()` in a debugger?

Like so,

```
items = request.headers.items()
import ipdb
ipdb.set_trace()   # check type of items; is it an iterable of pairs?
```

Comment: I think this could be clearer. Just use `{k:v for k, v in request.headers.items()}` as the thing to pass to json.dumps(thing).

Comment: @MrMesees hello, i faced the same issue, i got string after json.dump, do you now hot to get dictionary from EnvironHeaders? i tried to convert string to dict but that move breaks request and appears 400 code "Bad Request!"

Comment: Headers can contain multiple values for the same key, and `{k:v for k, v in headers.iteritems()}` will only yield one of those values per key.  It would be better to use [`headers.to_wsgi_list()`](https://tedboy.github.io/flask/generated/generated/werkzeug.Headers.to_wsgi_list.html) method instead to produce a list of pairs suitable for json serialization, so as not to lose any data here.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```
json.loads(json.dumps({**request.headers}))
```